# Не отправляется письмо в PHPMailer

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

У меня выскакивает ошибка, когда я запускаю код

```
<?php

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

 // Load Composer's autoloader
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Mail
{
    public static function sendMail($subject, $body, $address)
    {
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
            $mail->Username = 'mysocialnetworkmailphp@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password = '232815q';
            $mail->setFrom('no-reply@howcode.org');
            $mail->addAddress($address);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                    echo 'Message sent!';
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Ошибка: 2020-04-25 10:14:20 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: ??????? ?????????? ?????????? ???? ???????????, ?.?. ?? ??????? ?????????? ?? ????????? ????? ?? ??????? ?????? ??????, ??? ???? ????????? ??? ????????????? ?????????? ??-?? ????????? ??????? ??? ????????????? ??????????. (10060)

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: запустите там, где поддерживается юникод, чтобы ошибка не была ??????

Comment: @ArchDemon где например?

Comment: git bash, linux консоль

Comment: Так мне нужно запускать именно на localhost xampp